# Why doesn't redux-form pass in the value from an option field as prop in the submit function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-form

**The Problem**

I have 2 simple redux form's.
They consist `title` and `subTitle` fields of type `text`.

One of the two forms uses another field type `select`.
I pass in an option like this:

```
<Field name="test" component="select">
        <option value="test">test</option>
</Field>
```

So I fill out the form and console log the props like this:

The general Form submit:
`<Form onSubmit={handleSubmit(submitTopic)}>`

The actual function that runs:

```
const submitTopic = props => {
    console.log(props);
    // dispatch(createTopic(test, topicTitle, topicSubTitle));
};
```

So I expect to see the title as the string I typed in in the form and the subTitle as the string I typed in. (works for both forms)
I also expect to see a third property called "test" with the string "test" as value in the second form.

But it's actually `undefined`

**The Code**

Here is the link to my repo:

https://github.com/dhuber666/CodeHUB

The files where all this happens are here:

[image]

The Admin.js file is where I import it and run it.

I made sure that each form has it's unique `identifier` when using the `reduxForm`helper method.

**A minimal Example to test out on Codesandbox**

https://codesandbox.io/s/w0mqnwqz9w

Here I recreated the app but just with the bare mininum to test this out. 
And I have the same problem here. I don't get the option value passed in into props.

The console.log for the props is in the file `Form` at line number `10`

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I am able to see the "test" value in console

Comment: That is very strange. Here is my console.log output:

Object {topicTitle: "Javascript", topicSubTitle: "asdfasdfasdfasdf"}
topicTitle: "Javascript"
topicSubTitle: "asdfasdfasdfasdf"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works when you try to select an option, it doesn't work when you directly submit without selecting because the value is undefined initially until onChange event is triggered.
if you want to skip that, You can provide a default value by creating a wrapper component for select.

Comment: Thank you so much, that was it. OMG :D